# Is an icon of Christ without a cross in the halo Orthodox Christian?

Tags: iconography

Is an icon of Christ without a cross in the halo Orthodox Christian? 
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the icon, or perhaps its name or the name of the iconographer?

Comment: Because art? Who makes the halo rules? And are halo crosses really that predominant? [Google shows tons of halos without crosses](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=halo+jesus&tbm=isch)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the artistic choices of a single unspecified artist.

Comment: "Is an icon of Christ without a cross in the halo Orthodox Christian?" What are you actually trying to ask here? Whether it is a particularly Eastern/Oriental Orthodox style of art? Whether it is an official style?

Answer (score 3):

See the [*Catholic Encyclopedia*](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11080b.htm): Halos were used in art among the pagans long before the Christian Era. In the monuments of Hellenic and Roman art, the heads of the gods, heroes, and other distinguished persons are often found with a disc-shaped halo, a circle of light, or a rayed-fillet.

This iconography was later adopted as a sacred symbol by both Buddhism and Christianity. In time, Christians also used the halo symbol not only for Jesus but also to distinguish the saints from other people present in the art.

Because it dates back to pagan times, the halo began without a cross, so you should see earlier (and even later) depictions of Jesus without a cross in the halo, but medieval artists began to merge the two symbols for greater visual effect.